# Git thinks a file within a symlinked directory has been deleted after recreating the symlink, how can I fix it?

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, symlink

I have a symlinked directory within my repository, which links to files elsewhere on the filesystem. For whatever reason, the symlink breaks every now and then, and it turns into a regular empty folder. So I deleted the empty folder, and recreated the symlink with `ln -s ../../ ext`, which appears to have worked as I can browse that folder and see the contents. But when I run `git status`, it appears all the files that should be visible within the `ext` folder are missing. How can I make git see that they are there again, within the symlinked directory?

This is on Ubuntu 18 by the way.

Comment: My coworker have the exact same issue, while I don't have any problem. We both run Windows 10 and have in our git global config `core.symlinks=true` , and when he checkout a branch where I recreated some symlinks, he sees in the diff that some folders. When I start a fresh repo clone into another directory, I do not have this behaviour. Did you by any chance, grasped the origin of your problem by the time ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just dont put a repo in a repo, its not worth it

Answer (score 0):

Your setup is odd, because Git does not *follow* symlinks, it just *stores* them.

That is, if you have a symbolic link `ext -> ../..` and you run `git add ext`, Git creates, in the index, an entry with mode `120000` (symlink) to store the blob contents `../..`.  Committing will create a commit that, when extracted, will create the symbolic link `ext` pointing to `../..`.  Git *will not* store any files *within* `ext` when it is storing this symbolic link.

If, on the other hand, you have an existing commit that contains files named `ext/foo` and `ext/bar`, and you clone this repository at this commit, or extract this commit into a new and otherwise empty work-tree, Git will see that in order to write to files named `ext/foo` and `ext/bar`, your OS requires that `ext` exists as a directory.  It will therefore *create* the empty *directory* `ext`, in which it will then create files `foo` and `bar` as your OS requires, so as to create files that to Git are merely named `ext/foo` and `ext/bar`.  These two names, `ext/foo` and `ext/bar`, will now be in the index, so that the next commit you make will also contain these two files.

It sounds like you:

1. cloned a repository (perhaps with `git clone --no-checkout`?);
2. manually created a symbolic link in the work-tree named `ext`, pointing to some existing directory (perhaps one with some files inside it);
3. convinced `git checkout` to create `ext/foo` and `ext/bar` without first removing the symbolic link `ext` and replacing it with a directory `ext`.

This is not a supported mode of operation<sup>1</sup> and you should not be surprised when it goes wrong.

---

<sup>1</sup>It leads to security issues: Git is meant not to write any files "outside" the work-tree area, and writing to files "under" a symbolic link to a directory outside the work-tree would allow this to occur.  Rather than carefully limit symbolic link usage, Git just generally doesn't store files "beyond" any link in the first place—though it's probably possible, through careful manipulation of the index and, at the OS level, the file system in which your work-tree resides, to trick Git manually.